# How to change a given control's properties via code?

Tags: c#, properties, controls

I am very new to programming. I tried changing the properties of a `ProgressBar` (`Style` to be exact) but I failed. I'd like help on how to change the properties through code. Here is the code:

```
 private void R3S9(int QuestionCount)
 {
     progressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle 1; 
 }
```

I can't get this to compile properly due to the `progressBar1.Style = ProgressBarSytle 1`. Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the style in this way:

```
// for continuous style
progressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Continuous;
```

Also there are two more styles Marquee and Blocks. Put a "." after ProgressBarStyle to access other members of the enum.

You can set the other styles like this:

```
// for marquee style
progressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;

// for blocks style
progressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Blocks;
```

Comment: Ok now I get it. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In C#, three kind of progress bar styles are available.

1. blocks
2. continuous
3. marquee

To access these style properties, use the following code:

```
//For continuous progress bar style

 progressBar.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Continuous;

//For blocks progress bar style

 progressBar.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Blocks;

//For marquee progress bar style

 progressBar.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
```